# Site Speed not showing in google analytics

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, google-analytics

I'm using Magento 1.9.1, and currently all of Google Universal Analytics is working, except I'm not seeing my page load times under behavior>site speed>overview. All fields are 0.00 sec.

I thought 1.9.1 came Universal Analytic ready. Do I need to post a line of code somewhere for page load speeds to be tracked? Or have I not enabled it somewhere?

Any help appreciated- Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.9.1.0 Universal Analytics was added, however you might not be seeing data because by default the sample rate defined by Google Analytics is 1%, meaning that only 1% of your traffic will have site speed data collected. You can find out more here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate

This will require overwriting a method in `Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga` in order to make the change.